# How to transform vector3 by angle?

Tags: three.js

I have question and I don’t know how to realize it. Let’s say I have 4 Vector3 and I want to increase each of them on the z-axis by 100 and at the same time keep the angle of these vectors (as in the picture). In other words, I need the vector to be greater along the z-axis by 100 and always parallel to the initial vector. I will be glad for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're asking for, try following the steps below to maintain the angle θ between your vector and the x-y plane while adjusting its length:

- Increase the Z-Component
- Find the length to extend in the Vector's Direction (Use the Pythagoras theorem)
- Then Normalize, then Scale
- Finally add the Extended Vector to the Original Vector

```
let originalVector = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
let unitVector = originalVector.clone().normalize();
originalVector.z += 100;
let originalLength = originalVector.length();
let newLength = Math.sqrt(originalLength**2 + 100**2);
let lengthToExtend = newLength - originalLength;
let extensionVector = unitVector.multiplyScalar(lengthToExtend);
let finalVector = originalVector.add(extensionVector);
```

If you have multiple vectors, repeat the above steps for each one.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your question implies that your "vector" is a line from point A to point B. Vectors represent single points in space relative to the origin point of the local coordinate system. Through Euclidean construction, you can create a line segment from two such points/vectors.

So, if this is what you're asking for, and you simply want `line2` to be 100 units from `line1` in the +z direction, just add 100 to the `z` values of both vectors that represent the line. The lines will remain parallel because you're applying the same translation transformation to both points.

If I'm misunderstanding, please add details about how a hypothetical `vector1` should transform into `vector2`.